# Kafka consumer group file not found at default location

Tags: apache-kafka

It is observerd that when data is sending through API from an external user to this real time portal, he is getting success response and when we are trying to see the data from reports, no data is found. I am trying to identify this issue.

In the infra, there is a Kafka Server with one broker only. When I try to see the list of consumers & producers, I didn't find the file of consumer group. Can anyone suggest where to search for that or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumer groups are stored in the `__consumer_offsets` topic.

Topics have files in the Kafka data location, but it's not directly readable from there

There's nothing built in to Kafka that'll allow you to see active producers.